# Swift For In loop not maintaining variable value in Archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a piece of code that works fine when deployed via Xcode directly onto the device but if I install the application via an adhoc archive it fails miserably.

This is the code, it is full of log statements as I wasn't able to utilise the debugger so I had to rely on the console output to work out what was happening.

```
    var status: ShipmentStatus = ShipmentStatus.NOT_READY
    let stopOrders = getStopOrders(true)

    for order in stopOrders{
        NSLog("Beginning Loop Shipment Status = %d", status.toRaw())
        let stopStatus = order.getStopOrderStatus()
        NSLog("%d Stop Status = %d", order.salesOrderHeader.salesOrderNo, stopStatus.toRaw())
        if(stopStatus == StopOrderStatus.READY_FOR_PICKING || stopStatus == StopOrderStatus.PARTIALLY_PICKED){
            return ShipmentStatus.READY_FOR_PICKING
        } else if(stopStatus == StopOrderStatus.PICKING_COMPLETE){
            status = ShipmentStatus.PICKING_COMPLETE
            NSLog("Shipment Status = %d", status.toRaw())
        } else if(stopStatus == StopOrderStatus.READY_FOR_DELIVERY || stopStatus == StopOrderStatus.PARTIALLY_DELIVERED){
            if(status != ShipmentStatus.PICKING_COMPLETE){
                status = ShipmentStatus.READY_FOR_DELIVERY
                NSLog("Shipment Status = %d", status.toRaw())
            } else {
                NSLog("Shipment Status is not changed")
            }
        } else if(stopStatus == StopOrderStatus.DELIVERY_COMPLETE){
            if(status != ShipmentStatus.PICKING_COMPLETE && status != ShipmentStatus.READY_FOR_DELIVERY){
                status = ShipmentStatus.DELIVERY_COMPLETE
                NSLog("Shipment Status = %d", status.toRaw())
            } else {
                NSLog("Shipment Status is not changed")
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog("Return Shipment Status = %d", status.toRaw())
    return status
```

The issue is that unless the first condition is matched (ie it returns the value as part of the loop) the variable `status` is always equal to `ShipmentStatus.NOT_READY`. If I check the logs I can see that at every loop iteration `status` is also equal to `ShipmentStatus.NOT_READY` but I can also see in the console that it is being set correctly during the iteration. So it seems to be treating the variable as if it has been declared inside the loop and creating a new copy for every iteration.

As I mentioned this only occurs if the project is bundled up into an archive and deployed over the air. When deployed directly onto the device the code works as expected. This happens on both iOS 7.1.2 and iOS 8. I have just tested using Xcode 6 GM and the issue still exists.

Has anyone seen behaviour like this in their code? The strange thing is I have other code which follows a similar pattern and it appears to be returning the expected value.

================

Just for clarification, this is the log output that I see when deployed using Xcode

```
[7454:60b] Beginning Loop Shipment Status = 0
[7454:60b] 10000221 Stop Status = 70
[7454:60b] Shipment Status = 60
[7454:60b] Beginning Loop Shipment Status = 60
[7454:60b] 10000222 Stop Status = 70
[7454:60b] Shipment Status = 60
[7454:60b] Beginning Loop Shipment Status = 60
[7454:60b] 10000223 Stop Status = 70
[7454:60b] Shipment Status = 60
[7454:60b] Return Shipment Status = 60
```

And when it is deployed via an archive the result is

```
<Warning>: Beginning Loop Shipment Status = 0
<Warning>: 10000221 Stop Status = 70
<Warning>: Shipment Status = 60
<Warning>: Beginning Loop Shipment Status = 0
<Warning>: 10000222 Stop Status = 70
<Warning>: Shipment Status = 60
<Warning>: Beginning Loop Shipment Status = 0
<Warning>: 10000223 Stop Status = 70
<Warning>: Shipment Status = 60
<Warning>: Return Shipment Status = 0
```

Comment: It's hard to know what the actual problem is, but from what you have said, this not a Swift problem, but a deployment issue that is causing order.getStopOrderStatus() to fail (based on your own account and logic).

Comment: order.getStopOrderStatus() is returning the expected result. So the log statement directly below it shows the expected value for each order. I can also see in the log that status is being assigned and then the log shows that status has the expected value. However in the next iteration of the loop status is reset back to the original value and after the loop has run the result returned is always the original value.

Comment: That is weird - that there would be a difference.  I haven't done the ad-hoc archive installation, but could you be using an old runtime?  And do you also have a class property that is also named status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem resolved but using what I would consider a workaround as I assume that because of the nature of the issue and the fact that it doesn't cause an issue when the app is deployed via Xcode that this a bug in the package builder.

The enum definition for ShipmentStatus was defined in the same Swift file as this function. So I moved the enum into a separate file and hey presto, the issue goes away.